# Import from tempate parent class a template member type without having to repeat the name

Tags: c++

I would like to import from template parent class a template type without having to type the name twice. Is it possible?

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct CPU
{
    using SimpleType = int;
    template<typename T> using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;
};

template<typename Target>
struct Pipeline : public Target
{
    using typename Target::SimpleType; // Ok, I don't have to type 'using SimpleType = typename Target::SimpleType'

    //template<typename T> using typename Target::Matrix; // Error

    template<typename T>
    using Matrix = typename Target::template Matrix<T>; // Ok BUT it repeats the name 'Matrix'

    void ff()
    {
        SimpleType x;
        Matrix<float> y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Pipeline<CPU> pipeline;
    pipeline.ff();
}
```

Comment: Bad news: using-declaration cannot name template-id (by current c++ grammar, source: cppreference.com).

Comment: @Elliott https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration , search for `template` after Notes. I don't consider it as a correct answer as OP's problem is not solved by it. However, I'm thinking about a namespace-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

As per current c++ grammar, you cannot have a template-id in a using-declaration ([source: cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)), so this won't work directly. Neither can you easily lift it to namespace-level (because there's no template namespace parameter) or simplify by having a simple traits class inside the class (because syntax would be the same as using it directly).

What you can do, in case you only use it to e.g. generating variables inside a calculation, is to have a generator function. When you have a `using Base::fn` declaration, it brings all such functions, including templates, into scope:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct id_t
{
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
id_t<T> id = {};

struct CPU
{
    using SimpleType = int;
    template<typename T> using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr auto gen_matrix_type(id_t<T>) -> Matrix<T> { return {}; }
};

template<typename Target>
struct Pipeline : public Target
{
    using typename Target::SimpleType; // Ok, I don't have to type 'using SimpleType = typename Target::SimpleType

    using Target::gen_matrix_type;

    void ff()
    {
        SimpleType x;
        // typename Target::template Matrix<float> y;
        auto y = gen_matrix_type(id<float>);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Pipeline<CPU> pipeline;
    pipeline.ff();
}
```

It's not the same thing that you ask for: you can't directly refer to the type from descendant class (you need `decltype(Pipeline<CPU>::gen_matrix_type(id<float>)` for that, instead of `Pipeline<CPU>::template Matrix<float>`), so it's not for all use cases, but might simplify the situation when you only need it inside the implementation, to generate empty variables. It can be extended to take ctor args as well, if needed.

---

Another alternative to consider is, whether `Matrix` should really be a member of `CPU`. Granted, you might want different `Matrix` templates for different base classes, so this means introducing another type argument; in some sense, it's like lifting a member function to a global function, or having an `operator` as a `friend` function rather than as a member function. Additional benefit is, you can make sure that for all descendants you have the same `template` type:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
 
template<typename Scope, typename T, typename = void>
struct MatrixType;
 
template<typename Scope, typename T>
using Matrix_t = typename MatrixType<Scope, T>::type;
 
struct CPU;
 
template<typename Scope, typename T>
struct MatrixType<Scope, T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<CPU, Scope>::value>::type>
{
    using type = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;
};
 
struct CPU
{
    using SimpleType = int;
};
 
template<typename Target>
struct Pipeline : public Target
{
    using Self = Pipeline;
    using typename Target::SimpleType; // Ok, I don't have to type 'using SimpleType = typename Target::SimpleType
 
    void ff()
    {
        SimpleType x;
        Matrix_t<Pipeline, float> y;
    }
};
```